# Dynamic ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My angular controller is

```
$scope.dyna = [
    { "name": "parshuram", "age": 24 },
    { "name": "Tejash", "age": 26 },
    { "name": "Vinayak", "age": 25 }
];
```

My html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in dyna">
     <td>{{test.name}}</td>
     <td>{{test.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tboody>
</table>
```

This works correctly, and outputs

```
Parshuram 24
Tejash    26
```

But if an another variable is added to my scope variable, I need to make changes in my html table:

```
  $scope.dyna = [
       { "name": "parshuram", "age": 24 ,"void": true},
       { "name": "Tejash", "age": 26,"void" : false }
  ];

  <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat= "test in dyna">
         <td>{{test.name}}</td>
         <td>{{test.age}}</td>

         <!-- I don't want to have to add this, the columns should be added dynamically -->
        <td>{{test.void}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tboody>
    </table>
```

In that case, can the columns be generated dynamically, for example by getting all my object variables from the scope?

Comment: check key,value method in ng-repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) can loop over object [key/values as well](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "test in dyna">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
        {{value}}
      </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However as noted in the docs linked above, there are a few limitations compared to an `ng-repeat` that works on arrays:

> - The JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys
>     returned for an object, so Angular relies on the order returned by the
>     browser when running for key in myObj. Browsers generally follow the
>     strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were defined,
>     although there are exceptions when keys are deleted and reinstated.
>     See the MDN page on delete for more info.
> - ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because
>     it's a prefix used by Angular for public ($) and private ($$)
>     properties.
> - The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and
>     will throw an error if used with one.

Comment: It works thanks i am not worried about order,does this method as any other limitation

Comment: @Parshuram Not that I know of no

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with (key,value) iteration.

Would be nice to have fiddle to verify but would be something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat= "test in dyna">
    <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in test">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

If at 'runtime', I don't know. Otherwise:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "test in dyna">
      <td ng-repeat="key in objectKeys(test)">{{test[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dyna = [
        { "name": "parshuram", "age": 24 },
        { "name": "Tejash", "age": 26 },
        { "name": "Vinayak", "age": 25 }
    ];

    $scope.objectKeys = function (object) {
      var keys = Object.keys(object);
      keys.splice(keys.indexOf('$$hashKey', 1))
      return keys;
    }

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17uhx1mh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<html>
<script src="library/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="practice.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="test1" ng-bind-html="result">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Angularjs

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('test1',['$scope','$compile','$sce',function($scope,$compile,$sce){
    $scope.dyna = [
    { "name": "parshuram", "age": 24 },
    { "name": "Tejash", "age": 26 },
    { "name": "Vinayak", "age": 25 }
];
$scope.result="<table><tbody>";
for(var i=0;i<$scope.dyna.length;i++){
        $scope.result+="<tr>";
        for(var key in $scope.dyna[i])
            if($scope.dyna[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
                $scope.result+='<td>'+$scope.dyna[i][key]+'</td>';
        $scope.result+="</tr>";
}
    $scope.result+="</tbody></table>";
    $scope.result=$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.result);
}]);
```

> This is another way, creating html in controller.

Comment: No i dont want to do this i am not playing in my controller, my html string is coming from server and i am just binding here so this will not work for me

Comment: this is a way for creating html dynamically, even for creating html in server side. but ng-repeat is simple way and better.

Answer (score -2):

just make it again put another ng-repeat in your loop for the test variable:

```
$scope.dyna = [{ "name": "parshuram", "age": 24 ,"void": true}, { "name": "Tejash", "age": 26,"void" : false }];

  <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat= "test in dyna">

           <td ng-repeat="t in test">{{test[t]}</td> // just like this
        </tr>
      </tboody>
    </table>
```